# Unable to import new fsimage using "hdfs namenode importCheckpoint"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I have a namenode whose fsimage is corrupted and i only have one fsimage available. I have a secondarynamenode which has the checkpoints available.
Now, i wanted to importCheckpoint to a new directory. 
Old directory: `cd /home/rakeshbharadwaj/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.4-ex2/nn`
New directory: I have changed in hdfs-site.xml to `/home/rakeshbharadwaj/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.4-ex2/new`

I tried to run `hdfs namenode importcheckPoint` and it gave me the following error

```
19/02/26 12:38:51 INFO common.Storage: Lock on /home/rakeshbharadwaj/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.4-ex2/new/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 5270@rakeshbharadwaj-VirtualBox
19/02/26 12:38:51 INFO namenode.FSImage: Storage directory /home/rakeshbharadwaj/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.4-ex2/new is not formatted.
19/02/26 12:38:51 INFO namenode.FSImage: Formatting ...
19/02/26 12:38:51 INFO common.Storage: Lock on /tmp/hadoop-rakeshbharadwaj/dfs/namesecondary/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 5270@rakeshbharadwaj-VirtualBox
19/02/26 12:38:51 WARN namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.doImportCheckpoint(FSImage.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1566)
19/02/26 12:38:51 INFO mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:50070
```

So, i have formatted the namenode by running `hdfs namenode -format`. And the format was successful. After the format there a new image formed **fsimage_0000000000000000000**

Now, i ran the `hdfs namenode -importCheckpoint` again and it gave me the following error.

```
19/02/26 12:30:47 WARN namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
java.io.IOException: Cannot import image from a checkpoint.  NameNode already contains an image in /home/rakeshbharadwaj/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.4-ex2/n
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1566)
```

Question: How do i solve this and get the fsimage from the checkpoint in the new directory.